# llegal string offset 'name' in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, model

i have this error:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: Illegal string offset 'name'
Filename: user/account.php
Line Number: 72
```

In the controller "account.php" i have this:

```
[...]
$account['account']  = $this->user_model->account($id);

$this->template->write_view('top_menu', 'top_menu');
$this->template->write_view('user', 'template/user/panel', $data, TRUE);
$this->template->write_view('left', 'template/public/menu');
$this->template->write_view('right', 'template/user/account',$account, TRUE);
$this->template->render();
```

In the "user_model.php" i have this:

```
public function account($id)
{
    $query = $this->db->get_where('users', array('id' => $id));

    if ($query->num_rows() == 1)
    {
        return $query->row();
    }
    else
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

and in the view i have this:

```
    <?php foreach ($account as $row)
    {
        (this is the line 72) echo $row['name'];
    }
    ?>
```

whats is the error? Thanks for your help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one in view to call name

```
<?php 
  echo $account->name;
?>
```

**EDIT**

Keep in view like my answer above and try to change your model like this

```
public function account($id)
{
    $query = $this->db->where(array('id' => $id))->limit(1)->get('users');

    if($query->num_rows())
        return $query->row();
    else
        return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: Hi kefy, that's the first thing I tasted, but I get this error "Trying to get property of non-object". Thanks for responding so quickly.

Comment: Sorry, I fixed. I had forgotten to delete the "foreach".

Comment: Yups congratulation but my advice update your model like my previouslly upadte my answer